# Basic message passing in chrome extension seems to fail

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have read the documentation and this should be basic but I can't seem to get those alerts to appear. What's wrong?

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function finder() {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {type: "feature"}, function(response) {
            console.log(response.farewell);
          });
        });
    }
</script>
<style>
    p {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width:200px;
        font-size:10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><a id="jira">Click to populate FE description</a></p>
<script>
var jira = document.getElementById('jira');
jira.addEventListener('click', finder, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Content Script:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert('sreceived');
    if (request.type == "feature") {
        alert('score!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Any errors in console (in any of two windows)?

Comment: Show your manifest.json file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline  blocks and inline event handlers](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution) (e.g. `<button onclick="...">`).

By above lines it is clear that your popup.html violates restrictions, which can be solved as follows:

Remove all `<script>` tags in `popup.html` and move the original code to `popup.js`.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script> <!-- Added this line -->
<style>
    p {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width:200px;
        font-size:10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><a id="jira">Click to populate FE description</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I did not literally copy-paste the code in `popup.js`. These are the changes I made:

1. [`chrome.tabs.getSelected()`](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-extensions/A5bMuwCfBkQ) is deprecated in favour of [`chrome.tabs.query()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query), so I updated `chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {});`
2. Commented out `console.log(response.farewell);` because there is no response handler from content script.

**Final popup.js**

```
function finder() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        "status": "complete",
        "currentWindow": true,
        "active": true
    }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
            type: "feature"
        }, function (response) {
            //console.log(response.farewell);
        });
    });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',= function() {
    document.getElementById('jira').onclick = finder;
});
```

***Cautions for manifest.json***

1. Ensured permissions are available as `"permissions":["tabs","<all_urls>"],`
2. Permissions for content script also

   ```
   "content_scripts": [
       {
         "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
         "js": ["content.js"]
       }
   ]
   ```

**Final manifest.json**

```
{
"name":"Basic Message Passing",
"description":"This demonstrates Basic Message Passing",
"browser_action":{
    "default_popup":"popup.html",
    "default_icon":"screen.png"
},
"manifest_version":2,
"version":"2",
"permissions":["tabs","<all_urls>"],
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Your content script was fine, so I did not change it.

### Demonstration

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Let me know if you need more information..

Comment: Your answer and mine had basically the same information (and you put more work into yours) so deleted mine, want you to get more points ;)

Comment: BTW, shouldn't Chrome log an error or a warning in console, if content security policy is violated, specifically if a script is inlined?

Comment: @Sudarshan Nice answer! I made [some changes](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13672406/revisions) to your answer to make it easier to find information. There's one thing which I did not remove: You recommended to comment `console.log` in the callback of `chrome.extension.sendMessage`, but that's not necessary: The callback is never called (it can be removed because it's optional).

Comment: Wow.  This is an incredible answer.  Thank you.  I would give you 100 accepted checks marks if I could!

Comment: @PAEz: What can i say .. thanks a ton :), i simply like your encouragement .. thanks X 100 :) :)

Comment: @RobW: Your mentoring is amazing .. i will take these suggestions for all my future posts .. thanks a lot

Comment: @Stan: Yes, it will log a message