# Opening a popup when a link is clicked inside a google chrome extension and insert a flash player in an extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hello (yep really long title)

I'm making my first google chrome extension and I'm having some trouble.

#### Information about the extension (just so you understand what I'm trying to make):

The extension is a "Radio", a flash player that plays music from a shoutcast url. And in the bottom of the flash player, 4 icons, 3 of them when clicked download a .pls file to open with VLC - WinAmp & iTunes and one is supposed to open a popup, and below information from the radio is displayed.

#### What I'm trying to do is:

1 - When a user clicks on the icon(in a red square in the picture below), a popup is supposed to open with a player (windows media player) and some information about the radio (the information is retrieved through an iframe)

2 - Display the flash player (and also the windows media player) in the extension, which doesn't seem to work...

--Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWCuh.png

#### The code:

1 - manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "Kombat Syndicate Radio Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Kombat Syndicate Radio",
"browser_action":   {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "19": "icons/icon.png",  
     "128": "icons/icon_128.png",
    "default_popup": "ksradio.html"
},

   "permissions": [
   "tabs"
    ]

}
```

2 - ksradio.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1><img style="margin-top:-15px;-webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-   gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(87%, transparent),  to(white));
" src="icons/ks_radio_icon.png" /><br />Kombat Syndicate Radio</h1>

<div align="center" text-align="center" id="content">
<div id="smallffmp3">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="140" height="80"   __idm_id__="1284874242">
    <param name="movie" value="http://tracks.kombatsyndicate.com/wp- content/plugins/shout-stream/smallffmp3.swf?url=http://85.25.118.16:7502/;&amp;title=Trac[kS]">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="sameDomain"><!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://tracks.kombatsyndicate.com/wp-content/plugins/shout-stream/smallffmp3.swf?url=http://85.25.118.16:7502/;&amp;title=Trac[kS]" width="140" height="80" __idm_id__="1284874243">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="sameDomain"><!--<![endif]-->
    </object><!--<![endif]-->
     </object>

     </div>

    <a href="http://85.25.118.16:7502/listen.pls" target="_blank"><img  src="icons/VLC_48.png" title="VLC Media Player"/></a>
    <a href="#" onClick="ksradiowmp()"><img src="icons/WMP_48.png" /></a>
    <a href="http://85.25.118.16:7502/listen.pls" target="_blank"><img  src="icons/WinAmp_48.png" title="WinAmp Media Player" /></a>
    <a href="http://85.25.118.16:7502/listen.pls" target="_blank"><img  src="icons/iTunes_48.png" title="iTunes" /></a>

    <iframe align="middle" style="display:block;" name="infos"  src="http://phpks.comoj.com/radioinfos.php" width="65%" height="70%" frameborder="0"   scrolling="no" seamless></iframe>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

3 - ksradio_wmp.html (the popup):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<h1><img style="margin-top:-15px;-webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit- gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(87%, transparent),  to(white));
" src="icons/ks_radio_icon.png" /><br />Kombat Syndicate Radio</h1>
<div style="overflow:hidden;" align="center" id="content">
<object id="MediaPlayer1" width="350" height="65" classid="clsid:6bf52a52-394a-11d3- b153-00c04f79faa6"  codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1 ,52,701">
<param name="FileName" value="http://85.25.118.16:7502/" />
<param name="animationatStart" value="true" />
<param name="transparentatStart" value="true" />
<param name="autoStart" value="true" />
<param name="showControls" value="true" />
<param name="fullScreen" value="false" />
<param name="url" value="http://85.25.118.16:7502/" />
<param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" />
<param name="autostart" value="1" />
<param name="showcontrols" value="1" />
<embed id="MediaPlayer1" width="350" height="65" type="application/x-mplayer2"   src="http://85.25.118.16:7502/" FileName="http://85.25.118.16:7502/"  animationatStart="true" transparentatStart="true" autoStart="true" showControls="true"  fullScreen="false" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"  autostart="1" showcontrols="1" />
   </object>
   <a href="http://85.25.118.16:7502/listen.pls"><img src="icons/VLC_48.png" title="VLC   Media Player"/></a>
   <a href="http://85.25.118.16:7502/listen.pls"><img src="icons/WinAmp_48.png" title="WinAmp Media Player" /></a>
   <a href="http://85.25.118.16:7502/listen.pls"><img src="icons/iTunes_48.png"   title="iTunes" /></a>
   <iframe style="display:block;" name="infos"   src="http://phpks.comoj.com/radioinfos.php" width="65%" height="70%" frameborder="0"   scrolling="no" seamless></iframe>

   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

4 - script.js:

```
function ksradiowmp() {
window.open("ksradio_wmp.html", "myWindow", "status=1, height=450, width=400, resizable=0, toolbar=no, directories=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no")

}
```

P.S: This is what the popup should look like:https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTBxn.png

So to resume, I need help with making a popup open from the extension, and displaying the flash player and the windows media player inside the extension.
I really hope that you guys will help :D
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminate all instances of

a) `value="http://tracks.kombatsyndicate.com/wp- content/plugins/shout-stream/smallffmp3.swf?url=http://85.25.118.16:7502/;&amp;title=Trac[kS]"`

b) `href="http://85.25.118.16:7502/listen.pls"`

c) `onClick="ksradiowmp()"` etc and etc

For more information refer this [Basic message passing in chrome extension seems to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670738/basic-message-passing-in-chrome-extension-seems-to-fail/13672406#13672406)

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm not really good with javascript..
But somehow I got the popup to work, kinda.. It doesn't only popup when I click on the icon(Like I want it to be), but it pops up when I click anywhere on the page..
what I added to script.js:
`document.addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('a#wmppop').addEventListener('click');
  ksradiowmp();
});`
And in the ksradio.html:
`<a href="#" id="wmppop"><img src="icons/WMP_48.png" /></a>`
Can you help me please?
I also need help with embeding a flash player in the extension..

Comment: You have added an event listener to whole document instead of icon\button, can you use document.getelementbyid(<your icon id here>).onclick = your function code;

Comment: Like this?:
`document.addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('wmppop').onclick = ksradiowmp();
});`

I did it like this, and it still open the popup wherever I click on the page and not only on the icon :(

Comment: Do this way [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351773/can-i-use-document-getelementbyidsomeid-onclick-for-tag-a), let me know if it still fails.

Comment: Awesome it works! Thanks!
Any idea about the flash player and the windows media player? How to embed them in the extension

Comment: you can play media files using HTML 5 ( Chrome supports it); That said do you need flash/media player for your requirement?

Comment: Not really, I just need a player that support shoutcast streaming. I tried in html 5 with `<audio controls src="http://85.25.118.16:7502/;">/<audio>` it works in local, but not in the extension..

Comment: `src="http://85.25.118.16:7502/;"` will never work in any chrome extension,  check [THIS](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#resourceLoading).

Comment: I got it to work. Everything seems to be working just fine, thanks for your help sir! Really appreciate it

Comment: Hello again, I need your help on another subjet :(

--> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871128/google-chrome-extension-popup-keeping-the-popup-running-even-when-its-closed)